# Webforms - 'existing contact' does not auto complete

Tags: webform-civicrm

Using the 'Existing Contact' field on Civicrm without being logged into an account, it is impossible to autocomplete the form.

When i am logged in i can enter any existing contacts email and the form auto completes. Am I missing something in permissions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ON the webform, the component that is the 'existing contact' has a 'permissions' check box - you need to use this to override the controls  but note, this is what prevents your database being searchable by the public, so you may be disclosing information that you don't mean to (thx JonG for better wording)

Comment: This is the correct answer - but be careful, this is an information disclosure issue if you're not limiting the contacts that can be viewed this way.